# reference request for $L^p(\partial\Omega)$ in real analysis textbooks

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Would anybody come up with a real analysis textbook which contains detailed introductory treatment of the space $L^p(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: If $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$ or at least lipschitz, one usually associate $\partial \Omega$ the $n-1$-Hausdorff measure. What exactly do you want to know about $L^p(\partial \Omega)$?

Comment: Are you concerned with standard properties of $L^p$ spaces or with some particular issue emerged from $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: I would like to know how exactly the measure on $\partial\Omega$ is defined with details and explanations and the definition of $L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: This [book](https://www.bookdepository.com/Measure-Theory-Fine-Properties-Functions-Ronald-F-Gariepy/9781482242386) contains basic definition of a measure and a chapter on Hausdorff measure. For general measure theory you may see Rudin's real and complex analysis. @Jack

Comment: @JohnMa: Thanks for your comment. Evans's book is interesting. Do you have a reference for what you said in the comment "If ∂Ω is $C^1$ or at least Lipschitz, one usually associate ∂Ω the $n−1$-Hausdorff measure"?

Comment: For what it's worth, if $\partial\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is an open connected subset of ${\mathbb R}^{n})$ is $C^2,$ then $\partial\Omega$ satisfies a uniform exterior sphere condition, which is much stronger than having $\sigma$-finite Hausdorff $(n-1)$-measure. (In fact, you can replace "Hausdorff" with "upper Minkowski".) See 2.11 on p. 29 of Gilbarg/Trudinger's **Elliptic Partial Differential . . .** (1983), and related is 15.13 in Mattila's **Geometry of Sets . . .** (1995) and 3.3.5 in Federer's **Geometric Measure Theory** (1969). Maybe these references will help with your question.